# Graph Model: How to mark items in Neo4J as Read/Viewed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

[EDITED]

I am trying to build an application that allows users to receive messages. The model looks something like this:

`(user:Person)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(message:Message)`

Multiple users can have the same message.

I am attempting to show this on the UI with the following query:

`MATCH (user:Person)-[:HAS_MESSAGE]->(message:Message) WHERE user.EmployeeId = 'XYZ123' RETURN message`

But on the UI, I want to indicate the messages that they have not yet seen.

What would be the best way to model this in the Neo4J? Should I use a Label or a property? Also, how do I update their read state in the same query?

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

Here is one approach.

When creating new `Message` nodes, assign `false` to a `wasRead` property on the `HAS_MESSAGE` relationship. Then, when you want to get unread messages (and, at the same time, mark them as having been read):

```
MATCH (user:Person)-[r:HAS_MESSAGE]->(message:Message)
WHERE user.EmployeeId = 'XYZ123' AND r.wasRead = false
SET r.wasRead = true
RETURN message
```

For better performance, you should consider creating an index on the Person/EmployeeId combination, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(EmployeeId)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot set indexes on relationships.

Comment: It almost worked, but I have an issue, the same message can be shared with multiple users, in that case how will that work?. currently when one user sees it, it marks it as read for all.